# How can I adjust a button (created in js) horizontally middle?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried "text-center" class, and other bootstrap classnames.

```
const evaluate = document.createElement('button');
evaluate.className="btn btn-outline-dark";
this.canvas.appendChild(evaluate);
evaluate.textContent = 'Calculate';
evaluate.id = 'eval';
```

Comment: add your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class `text-center` to the parent. Try adding a `div` with this class name and append the button to it. Here is an example:

```js
const parent = document.createElement('div');
parent.className = 'text-center';
const evaluate = document.createElement('button');
evaluate.className="btn btn-outline-dark";
evaluate.textContent = 'Calculate';
evaluate.id = 'eval';  
parent.appendChild(evaluate);
document.body.appendChild(parent);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add style `text-align` 
see this reference page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.id = 'eval'
btn.className='btn btn-outline-dark';
btn.textContent = 'Calculate';
btn.style = 'text-align:center';

this.canvas.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.